# Obtener la primera letra de cada palabra - FPDF - PHP

Tags: php, fpdf

buen día

Me encuentro trabajando en un formulario con FPDF y en mi base de datos tengo la columna "nombre" y quiero que el nombre "CORPORACIÓN GRAN FORMATO SAC" solo me imprima "CGFS".

Alguien sabe como ayudarme?

Comment: Que has intentado ?

Comment: Prueba con esto a ver si es lo que necesitas: `$str = 'CORPORACIÓN GRAN FORMATO SAC';
$result = preg_replace( '/\b(\S)[^\s]*/m','', $str);
$result = preg_replace('/[ ]/m', '', $result); ` result sera: CGFS

Comment: Mejor hazlo todo con esto: preg_replace( '\b(\w)[^\s]*\s*/m','$1',$str) no necesitas del otro

Comment: Prueba con `foreach(explode(' ',$nombre) as $p) $siglas .= $p[0];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una expresión regular para extraer las primeras letras. La siguiente expresión  puedes utilizarla: `'/\b(\w)[^\s]*\s*/m'`.

La expresión dice: `\b` desde el inicio de una palabra `(\w)` captura una letra  y mantenla como un  grupo `[^\s]*` continua por  todos los caracteres que no son espacios hasta `\s*` encontrar uno o mas espacios. Se repite ese ciclo hasta el final.

En PHP podrías usarlo así:

```
$re = '/\b(\w)[^\s]*\s*/m';
$str = 'CORPORACIÓN GR AN FORMATO SAC';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

NOTA: $str es el nombre del que quieras extraer las primeras letras. Aqui está solo como ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias, me ha ayudado bastante, pero me ayuda con el texto de prueba pero cuando intento jalar los datos de la db me da el siguiente error:
"Notice: Array to string conversion in ../../../.."

Comment: Puedo ver cómo estás poniendo la línea ya con los datos de la BD?

Comment: En todo caso nueve el Carlos de la columna a la variable $str primero y utilizas eabvariqble. Lo hiciste así?

Comment: Ya está, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Una solución podría ser usar las funciones `explode()` y `str_split()`.

Por ejemplo así:

```
$text = "CORPORACIÓN GRAN FORMATO SAC";

$arrayText = explode(" ", $text);

$acronym = "";

foreach ($arrayText as $word)   {
  $arrayLetters = str_split($word, 1);
  $acronym =  $acronym . $arrayLetters['0'];
} 

echo $acronym ;
```

Ahí transformamos el texto en array con la función `explode()` estableciendo el espacio como separador. De esa forma, cada índice de `$arrayText` contendrá una palabra distinta.

Luego recorremos ese array con un `foreach` y vamos guardando en un nuevo array cada palabra dividida letra por letra indicándole el "1" como segundo argumento a la función `str_split()`.

Ese resultado estará en `$arrayLetters` cuyo primer índice contendrá siempre la primera letra de cada palabra. Todas esas letras las vamos a ir guardando en `$acronym`.

Finalmente imprimimos el acrónimo completo que contiene todas las primeras letras unidas.

Revisa las documentaciones de:
[explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) y [str_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-split.php)